# Initializing a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have some code like

```
// Includes, namespace and prototypes
#include "template.h"
#include "Global.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Gesture.h"
#include "Touch.h"


using namespace AGK;

Gesture currentGesture;

// Begin app, called once at the start
void app::Begin( void )
{
    SetupEnvironment(ENV_ANDROID);
    CreateBackground();
}
```

How would I call `currentGesture`'s constructor in this context so I can utilize it?  I know it isn't called by merely defining it above `app::Begin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is.

```
Gesture currentGesture;
```

defines a variable called `currentGesture` with external linkage and global scope. The constructor is called before entry in `main`, so the variable is alive and well by that point. You can use it in this translation unit as `currentGesture` or `::currentGesture`.

Other translation units will have to declare it first:

```
extern Gesture currentGesture;
```

Comment: It seems like I've got other problems then o.0.  Thanks for clarifying!